# Did Facebook Connect add Email Permission as an extended permission?

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk

Last I saw that 'email' permission in the authentication process was part of the initial dialog (along with basic information) for all apps. However, today I noticed that for my app it shows as an additional step (like extended permissions) after the user has accepted the initial authentication. See the screenshot:
[image: Screenshot]

I still see other sites/apps with old-style authentication (email in the first step). I wonder if I am doing something wrong with the permissions or app settings that is causing it? This is how my LoginUrl looks like

https://www.facebook.com/dialog/oauth?client_id=[app_id]&redirect_uri=[redirect_uri]&state=[state_code]&scope=email&display=popup

In the App settings on Facebook in the 'Auth Dialog' > 'Authenticated Referrals' > 'User & Friend Permissions' I have added 'email' and 'publish_actions' permissions.